# What is the name for code automation or automatic code insertion on Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I researched a little but the problem is I don't know the name of what I'm looking for =/

I have my personal framework that handles several common tasks in my projects and I also have some item templates to be used with that framework. I'd like to add code to specific classes (automatically) when I created a new class using my item template. I tried researching for `code automation in VS` `add code item template` and a lot of other weird word combinations...

I'll exemplify what I mean:

I have a class named `Dandoran` already created in a class library. Then I add a custom item template and on that moment I update class `Dandoran` with some specific code.

1. There's already a class in my class library named `Dandoran`
2. I create a new class, using my custom item template creation and name it `Tatooine`
3. At this moment, I (by I understand the item template or code automation, it's not really me going there and adding code) update class `Dandoran` with a code let's say this:

   public static void HelloImCustomCodeAutomaticallyGenerated(){}

Does anyone know the name of this? And if you'd also have some sources, but only the name of the feature would already be great, since I could then start my research.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean [Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx)?

Comment: Hey @Jcl, thanks but no. I do know Code Snippets. I guess I can't even explain what I want xD. Please, check my updated answer and included step by step to see if it helps you understand. Thanks.

Comment: Then more likely you are trying to use [T4 templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit) (**T**ext **T**emplate **T**ransformation **T**oolkit) for code generation

Comment: @Jcl thanks, I'm reading about it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are serching for Code Generation and T4 Text Templates?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Comment: Thank you I'm reading about it right now. I see that it's talking about creating files, does it also work for updating exising files?

Comment: Never mind! It does look like that's what I'm looking for! Thanks!